# Quick way for assigning a value to each member of a group in R

Tags: r, loops, optimization

I need to attribute a weight to each member of a group.
I have made the following loop to create the `weights_ind` vector (vector of individual weights), but my loop is too slow (2 seconds for 2000 individuals) :

```
# Data example
   n.group = 10
   n.tot = 1000
   groups = sample(1:10, n.tot, replace = TRUE)
   weights_by_group = rexp(n.group, rate = 1)


   weights_ind = rep(NA, n.tot)
     for(i in 1:n.tot){
     for(j in 1:n.group) {
     if(groups[i] == j) 
       weights_ind[i] = weights_by_group[j]
     }}
```

Which faster function may I use in my case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the groups are numbered starting at 1, you can use the `groups` vector to index the `weights_by_group`vector.

```
weights_ind = weights_by_group[groups]
```

On my computer, for 2000 individual, this takes about 10 microseconds.

If your groups were not numeric, you could name the `weights_by_group` vector with the group identifier, and still  use the `groups` to index:

```
groups = sample(letters[1:n.group], n.tot, replace = TRUE)
weights_by_group = rexp(n.group, rate = 1)
names(weights_by_group) = letters[1:n.group] 

weights_ind = weights_by_group[groups]
```

Comment: Perfect. It was exaclty what I need. Thanks a lot and happy new year